# Angular Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined debug

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a fairly large angular app, and I have recently been getting the error:

```
Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
```

But the stacktrace I am given has no relevance to my code - it just gives me where the error is in the angular code.

Is there a way to debug this issue so I know where in my code this error is happening? Right now I am simply taking guesses and hoping that it works, which is highly inefficient, obviously.

Comment: well, we can't tell you anything with the information you provided so far.  I would recommend, however, using the full `Angular.js` and not `angular.min.js` for more descriptive errors.

Comment: and that does not necesary means 'fn' is in your code. it can be an argument you passed to angular core

Comment: it could be that you are passing a value of undefined to a callback... or you are accidentally overriding an internal function... without a recreated issue we won't be able to offer much help

Comment: Thanks... I am using the full angular.js. I always seem to run into these types of issues and angular does not tell me where in my code the error is happening, so I am always on a wild goose chase. I was hoping there was some way to be able to log this error from my code somehow. I don't understand a point to a stacktrace if it does not show where the error originated.

Comment: As my app grows, this is becoming a much more annoying issue and is definitely not a "scalable problem" if that makes sense

Comment: @girlcode still makes sense in 2022. Maybe easier to rip out angular than to debug.